# How To Play Youtube Videos in Windows Phone using Silverlight Media Framework

Tags: c#, silverlight, youtube, windows-phone-8

I have a Link, an ID (all metadata about a Youtube URL) and I want to play the video, using SMF player in my Windows Phone 8 app. Is this possible?

Comment: i am working on Windows phone 8.. add this also.. :)

Answer (score -1):

i think you can use Media element to stream videos

[Audio and video for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207066%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#tag_mediaelement_obj)

Comment: Youtube videos are of .flv format we can't play flv videos in Media Element :/